# Okhttp interceptor doesn't see request's Content-type header

Tags: kotlin, http-headers, retrofit2, okhttp

I need to create an `OkHttp interceptor` which reads value of request's `Content-Type` header (POST request with body). Unfortunately, when I try to access it by `request.headers`, it's not there (I could see other custom headers, but not `Content-Type`). Yet, I could clearly see it in logs from `HttpLoggingInterceptor`.

I'm using `Retrofit`

Sample code:

```
//versions:
//okHttp: 4.10.0
//retrofit: 2.9.0

interface API {
    @Headers("secret: aaa", "aaa: AAA", "bbb: BBB", "Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("/post")
    suspend fun echoPOST(@Body bodyData: BodyData): Response<String>
}

data class BodyData(val secret: String = "aaaa", val nonsecret: String = "bbb")

val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(
                HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
            )
            .addInterceptor(MyInterceptor())
            .build()
val testRetrofitClient = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://httpbin.org")
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(httpClient)
            .build()

val api = testRetrofitClient.create(API::class.java)

suspend fun testRequestPOST() {
        try {
            val response = api.echoPOST(BodyData())
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Timber.e(e)
        }
}
```

interceptor:

```
class MyInterceptor : Interceptor {
    override fun intercept(chain: Chain): Response {
        val request = chain.request()
        val response = chain.proceed(request)
        Log.d("HTTP", "Content-Type: ${request.header("Content-Type")}")
        Log.d("HTTP", "request headers: ${request.headers.joinToString { it.first }}")
        return response
    }
}
```

---

when call is triggered, Logcat shows:

```
// output from HttpLoggingInterceptor
--> POST https://httpbin.org/post
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 35
secret: aaa
bbb: bbb123
ccc: ccc123
{"nonsecret":"bbb","secret":"aaaa"}

// output from MyInterceptor
Content-Type: null
request headers: secret, bbb, ccc
```

So `Content-Type` header is present in request (as logged by `HttpLoggingInterceptor`) but it's not visible in `MyInterceptor`

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the RequestBody, which has this information.